# Mongo Java Driver Iterator authentication issue

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, ssl, iterator, mongo-java-driver

I'm having a weird issue while trying to iterate over a collection.
I'm using SpringBoot and Mongo Java Driver and can connect and authenticate fine to MongoDB on docker-compose, and authenticate.
But when this part of code runs it gives an error.

```java
  @Autowired
  private MongoCollection<Document> collection;

@Scheduled(initialDelay = 112500,fixedRate = 3600000) //1 hour 3600000
    public void sendEngagementNotification() {

        Date timeNow = new Date();

        FindIterable<Document> iterable = collection.find();

        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = iterable.iterator();

        try {

            while (cursor.hasNext()) {

                 ...

            }
        }
```

It gives me this stack trace:

```
mongo | 2020-03-30T18:01:18.044+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 192.168.240.20:56152 #2 (2 connections now open)
mongo | 2020-03-30T18:01:18.058+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn2] received client metadata from 192.168.240.20:56152 conn2: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|sync", version: "3.12.2" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "4.19.76-linuxkit" }, platform: "Java/IcedTea/1.8.0_212-b04" }
mongo | 2020-03-30T18:01:18.062+0000 I  SHARDING [conn2] Marking collection admin.system.users as collection version: <unsharded>
mongo | 2020-03-30T18:01:18.289+0000 I  ACCESS   [conn2] SASL SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for user on notification from client 192.168.240.20:56152 ; AuthenticationFailed: SCRAM authentication failed, storedKey mismatch
mongo | 2020-03-30T18:01:18.445+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 192.168.240.20:56152 (1 connection now open)

notification  | 2020-03-30 18:01:18.450  INFO 20 --- [   scheduling-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2}] to mongo-notification:27017 because there was a socket exception raised by this connection.
notification  | 2020-03-30 18:01:18.456 ERROR 20 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
notification  | 
notification  | com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='user', source='notification', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.wrapException(SaslAuthenticator.java:201) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$300(SaslAuthenticator.java:40) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:78) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:47) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.doAsSubject(SaslAuthenticator.java:207) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:47) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:156) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:63) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:129) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:50) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:398) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:115) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:101) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:92) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:126) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:728) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:725) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withReadConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:463) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:725) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:89) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:196) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:143) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:92) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at notification_service.EngagementTask.sendEngagementNotification(EngagementTask.java:42) ~[classes!/:na]
notification  |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
notification  |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
notification  |     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
notification  |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
notification  |     at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
notification  |     at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
notification  |     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_212]
notification  |     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_212]
notification  |     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_212]
notification  |     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_212]
notification  |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_212]
notification  |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_212]
notification  |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
notification  | Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server mongo-notification:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Authentication failed.", "code": 18, "codeName": "AuthenticationFailed"}
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:303) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:259) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslContinue(SaslAuthenticator.java:162) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$200(SaslAuthenticator.java:40) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:67) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar!/:na]
notification  |     ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Any suggestion on another way to get all the documents from a collection?

Edit 1: It might be a problem with ssl!? The Jar is working fine with a mongodb container with no SSL enabled. Might it be because its self signed? What's the issue here?

Edit 2: Also is it normal for the iterator to open a connection? Is there a way to configure it?

Answer (score 2):

As I am understanding, You are trying to create multiple connections to MongoDB based on the Scheduler. And as I can see from the log, you are using the below credentials.

```
    Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='user', source='notification', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
```

I believe, since Default Database in MongoDB is test so it is possible that you might be hitting to test DB. Please change this to the admin Database which may solve it as that is the common db where users created. 
You can use below spring property to switch the Db to the admin so that it will be picked.

```
    spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, forgot to mention I'm using Mongo Java Driver. But yes I figured iterable.iterator() is creating a new connection every time is called. But I can't figure how to fix this.

Comment: Since User creation is managed through admin database, so I suggested configuring the same so try using the authentication-database property as mentioned in my answer

Comment: use $MONGODB_APPLICATION_DATABASE
db.createUser({user: '$MONGODB_APPLICATION_USER', pwd: '$MONGODB_APPLICATION_PASS', roles:[{role:'readWrite', db:'$MONGODB_APPLICATION_DATABASE'}]}) the user for my microservice is being created this way. I'm using the exact same thing on a mongo container without ssl and works just fine. I also set authentication database to the one where the user is being created with no luck.the problem is using this mongo in this docker-compose that is SSL enabled. I don't know if it my be an issue with self signed certificates or what.

Comment: Yes. It was not a problem with the code. Some issue with docker. Don't know what exactly tho. But I reinstalled everything and it started to work. Thanks for your inputs.